# Total count of Theorem like environments - In all chapters

Tags: thmtools, totcount

I am using the following structure to define my custom theorem-like `Prob` environment using the `thmtools` package.

I want to include the total number of problems in the introduction. For this I am using `totcount` package. This MWE shows `\total{Prob}` as 3, but it should be 5 (2+3).

Please guide me how to define `\theProb` so that `\total{Prob}` can give total number of problems from Chapter 1 and Chapter 2.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{totcount}


\declaretheoremstyle[
headfont=\small\bfseries,
notefont=\mdseries, notebraces={(}{)},
bodyfont=\normalfont,
]{probStyle}

\declaretheorem[style=probStyle,name={},numberwithin=chapter]{Prob}
\renewcommand{\theProb}{\thesection.\arabic{Prob}}


\regtotcounter{Prob}



\begin{document}


    \frontmatter

    \chapter{Introduction}

    This book contains \total{Prob} Problems


    \mainmatter


    \chapter{First}

    \section{Exercises}

    \begin{Prob}
        Problem 1 Chap 1

    \end{Prob}

    \begin{Prob}
        Problem 1 Chap 1

    \end{Prob}

    \chapter{Second}

    \section{Another Exercise}

    \begin{Prob}
        Problem 1 Chap 2

    \end{Prob}

    \begin{Prob}
        Problem 2 Chap 2

    \end{Prob}


    \begin{Prob}
        Problem 3 Chap 2

    \end{Prob}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Technically it's not really about `\theProb` (which only displays the count); but `\c@Prob`, the LaTeX-level macro that handles the count.

Comment: Here \theProb resets with each chapter.  \total{Prob} is reporting the last one.  How to count such counter across all chapters, to get total count finally.

Comment: thats exactly the problem. A possible algorithm would be to store all the counter values before each reset, in this case the `\cahpter`s, and add them together in the end. I wonder if this has been implemented alredy or if there is a clever way that is not so brute force style.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The resetting feature of counters is a point where `totcount` may fail.

The `xassoccnt` package associates a second counter to the `Prob` counter and increases this `totalprobs` counter every time `Prob` is increased, but the `totalprobs` counter is not reset automatically.

Declaring it as `\NewTotalDocumentCounter` gives the value via `\TotalValue` right at any place in the document body, since the last value is stored at the end of the previous run.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\usepackage{xassoccnt}



\declaretheoremstyle[
headfont=\small\bfseries,
notefont=\mdseries, notebraces={(}{)},
bodyfont=\normalfont,
]{probStyle}

\declaretheorem[style=probStyle,name={},numberwithin=chapter]{Prob}

\NewTotalDocumentCounter{totalprobs}
\DeclareAssociatedCounters{Prob}{totalprobs}
\renewcommand{\theProb}{\thesection.\arabic{Prob}}





\begin{document}


    \frontmatter

    \chapter{Introduction}

    This book contains \TotalValue{totalprobs} Problems


    \mainmatter


    \chapter{First}

    \section{Exercises}

    \begin{Prob}
        Problem 1 Chap 1

    \end{Prob}

    \begin{Prob}
        Problem 1 Chap 1

    \end{Prob}

    \chapter{Second}

    \section{Another Exercise}

    \begin{Prob}
        Problem 1 Chap 2

    \end{Prob}

    \begin{Prob}
        Problem 2 Chap 2

    \end{Prob}


    \begin{Prob}
        Problem 3 Chap 2

    \end{Prob}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @RamaKrishnaMajety: You're welcome. Happy TeXing!

Comment: Nice! "Look son, I got a package fot this..." :) +1 anyways and welcome back

Comment: @Ruben: Thanks ;-) `xassoccnt` has some nice features. And I know the author personally (at least I think so ;-))

Comment: Haha, I hope so... I'll check the code briefly to see the features

Comment: @Ruben: Oh my, don't check the code , rather read the manual. The code is very 'hidden'

Answer (score 4):

Declare a new total counter `allprobs`

```
\newtotcounter{allprobs}
```

and increment it each time you use the theorem by adding the following option to `\declaretheorem`:

```
\declaretheorem[...,postheadhook=\stepcounter{allprobs}]{Prob}
```

Then you can access the total number of these theorem-like environments by `\total{allprobs}`.